# How to understand the Definitions of existential and disjunction of intuitionistic logic.

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

In the testbook I have learnt that with the natural deduction rules:
$ A \lor B \to (A \to C) \to (B \to C) \to C$

$\exists x A \to \forall x ( A \to B) \to B$

after put $\bot$ into C, B respectively, we get disjunction and existential of intuitionistic logic:

$A \lor B := \lnot A \to (\lnot B \to \bot)$

$\exists x A := \lnot \forall x \lnot A$

---

My question: what's the meaning of putting a $\bot$ here, and why we can constuct intuitionistic disjunction and existential in such a manner?

Comment: You should probably add a few more parentheses for clarity. For example, do you mean $\neg A \to (\neg B \to \bot)$ or $(\neg A \to \neg B) \to \bot$?

Comment: I think you've gotten it backwards. Only in classical logic can we define $\lor$ and $\exists$ this way. Intuitionist logic does not permit such definitions.

Comment: You can only conclude that $A \lor B$ implies $\lnot A \rightarrow (\lnot B \rightarrow \bot)$ and $\exists x \, A$ implies $\lnot \forall x \lnot A$.  In intuitionistic logic, these are indeed valid implications; but the converses are not valid.

Comment: Somewhat interestingly, though, in the internal language of a topos (a modification of intuitionistic logic to include some type theory), you *can* prove that $A \lor B$ is equivalent to $\forall C : \Omega, (A \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow C$.  And similarly, if $B$ is not a free variable in a proposition term $A$, then $\exists x:X, A$ is equivalent to $\forall B : \Omega, (\forall x:X, A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B$.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two things (two pairs rather) being defined here.

- Your textbook gives the rules $A \lor B \to (A \to C) \to (B \to C) \to C$ and $(\exists x : A(x)) \to \forall x (A(x) \to C) \to C$ which specify how disjunctions $\lor$ and existential formulas $\exists x : A(x)$ are used during a proof. For example to first rule tells us that in order to prove that $C$ follows from $A\lor B$ we must give a proof that $C$ follows from $A$ and an additional proof that $C$ follows from $B$. More specifically, the rules you listed are the elimination rules of $\lor$ and $\exists$ respectively. (Pretty much the same definition [can be used in type theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265457/can-function-types-be-represented-using-sigma-types/4265473#4265473) to define sum and $\Sigma$ types)
- To clarify matters, the second pair of definitions should rather be written as
  $$
   A \lor_c B := \neg A \to \neg B \to \bot
   \hspace{3em}
   \exists_c x: A(x) := \neg \forall x: \neg A(x).
  $$
  The use of different symbols $\lor_c$ and $\exists_c$ hopefully highlights that they differ from $\lor$ and $\exists$. They are what you could call "classical versions" of $\lor$ and $\exists$ inside of intuitionistic logic and they indeed behave like the classical counterparts. For example you can intuitionistically prove that
  $$
   \neg \forall x: A(x) \leftrightarrow \exists_cx:\neg A(x)
  $$
  which is not possible if we have $\exists$ instead of $\exists_c$ on the right. The two quantifiers are connected though, since we can also show
  $$
    \exists x: A(x) \to \exists_cx: A(x)  ~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~
    \exists_cx: A(x) \leftrightarrow \neg \neg \, \exists x: A(x) 
  $$